# how to remember which href your iframe is pointing to upon browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have a webpage that contains an iframe that changes to different pages depending on what the user clicks in the menu bar.  Everything works fine except I don't like it when I click "refresh" on the browser and it forgets which page I'm on and it reloads the default page.  How do I get it to remember which page I was browser at?

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="HyperLink1" runat="server" href="Page1.aspx" target='contentframe'>Page1</a></li>
    <li><a id="HyperLink2" runat="server" href="Page2.aspx" target='contentframe'>Page2</a></li>
    ...
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <iframe name='contentframe' src='Page1.aspx'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: update the url or set a cookie. just 2 options

Comment: a 3rd is you could store the url in the session

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways

you go over Server Site Session (only now how to do this in **PHP** not in **ASPX**) or you go over a **Javascript** Cookie

**Javascript**

**use jQuery with Cookie plugin to set a cookie**

1. set in Page1, Page2 the Cookie

   `$.cookie('page', 'page1.aspx');` // for page 2
2. on your site you read the cookie and set the src of the **iframe** from the cookie

   `$('#iframeID').src($(.cookie('page'));`

But JS is not a good solution for this if possible use a server site session variable.

Comment: thanks!  I used server side session variable and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
localstorage.iframeurl = 'URL';
```